# Получение значения из составного раскрывающегося списка

Tags: javascript

Есть структурированный объект, содержащий данные о лицах, который имеет 3 вложенных объекта, соответственно для юридических лиц, физических лиц и арбитражных управляющих, которые, в свою очередь, содержат индексированный массив содержащий информацию о конечных лицах

```
{не-клиенты}
    идентификатор объекта = 'nc'
    {юридические лица}
        идентификатор подобъекта = 'yl'
        описание = '- юридические лица -'
        [имя инн огрн адрес]
        [имя инн огрн адрес]
        [имя инн огрн адрес]
        ...
    {физические лица}
         идентификатор подобъекта = 'fl'
         описание = '- физические лица -'
         [имя адрес]
         [имя адрес]
         [имя адрес]
        ...
    {арбитражные управляющие}
        Идентификатор подобъекта = 'au'
        описание = '- арбитражные управляющие -'
        [имя инн СРО адрес]
        [имя инн СРО адрес]
        [имя инн СРО адрес]
        ...
```

Я создал раскрывающийся список который последовательно включил организации, потом физ. лиц, потом управляющих. Список принял следующий вид:

[image: Раскрывающийся список]

Теперь мне надо написать `onchange` функцию для этого списка, чтобы она пошарила по объекту, нашла в нем соответствующие значения, например

```
 name:"ООО «АТЕ ФУД»",
 inn:"7731284520",
 ogrn:"1157746508040",
 address:"121596, Город Москва, Улица Горбунова, Дом 2, Строение 204, Комната 48"
```

и подставила их куда надо. Но учитывая составной характер объекта я не знаю как правильно связать значение `value` раскрывающегося списка и соответствующую позицию в объекте. Как это лучше сделать? Я вижу 2 пути:

1. Каждое `value` складывается конкатенацией из идентификатора подобъекта + порядкового номера записи в массиве следующим образом:

   `<option value='yl1'>ООО "КБМ"</option>`

   `<option value='yl2'>ООО "АТЕ ФУД"</option>`

   `<option value='yl3'>ООО "Смартори"</option>`

   `<option value='fl1'>Петров Петр Петрович</option>`

Потом функция эту строку обратно "разрывает" на две и ищет соответствующее значение.

2. К каждому `value` "прикрепить" соответствующий объект, но я не уверен, будет ли это достаточно экономно по ресурсам. Как лучше реализовать этот момент?

P.S.: Моя "база данных"

```
nonclient = {};

nonclient.yl = [

{
    name:"ООО «КБМ»",
    inn:"5018048203",
    ogrn:"1025002031405",
    address:"141075, Московская обл., г. Королев, пр. Космонавтов, д. 12А",
    address1:"129110, г. Москва, ул. Гиляровского д. 65, стр. 1, пом. XVI Ч., ком. 39, эт. 5",
    nameLong:"ООО Компания «Большая Медведица»"
},

{
    name:"ООО «АТЕ ФУД»",
    inn:"7731284520",
    ogrn:"1157746508040",
    address:"121596, Город Москва, Улица Горбунова, Дом 2, Строение 204, Комната 48"    
},

{
    name:"ООО «Смартори»",
    inn:"7733223201",
    ogrn:"1157746154312",
    address:"125445, город Москва, шоссе Ленинградское, дом 112, корпус 4"  
}

]

nonclient.fl = [

{
    name:'Петров Петр Петрович',
    address:'г. Сочи ул. Зеленая д. 25'
},

{
    name:'Сидоров Сидор Сидорович',
    address:'г. Нарьян-Мар Ленинский проспект д.1'
}
]

nonclient.au = [
{
    name:'Михайлов Михаил Михайлович',
    inn:'987654321',
    sro:'Союз Арбитражных управляющих г. Бердянска',
    address:'г. Бердянск, а/я "Михайлов М.М."'
}
]

nonclient.allegiance ='nonclient'

nonclient.yl.property='yl';
nonclient.yl.description=' - Организации - ';

nonclient.fl.property='fl';
nonclient.fl.description=' - Физические лица - ';

nonclient.au.property='au';
nonclient.au.description=' - Арбитражные управляющие - ';

Object.defineProperty(nonclient, 'allegiance', {enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty(nonclient.yl, 'property', {enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty(nonclient.yl, 'description', {enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty(nonclient.fl, 'property', {enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty(nonclient.fl, 'description', {enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty(nonclient.au, 'property', {enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty(nonclient.au, 'description', {enumerable: false});
```

Моя фукция для генерации выпадающего меню:

```
function setList(exportList, dataBase){

    exportList.textContent = '';
    let blankOpt = document.createElement('option');
    blankOpt.textContent='Выберите значение';
    blankOpt.className += 'grey';
    exportList.appendChild(blankOpt);

    for (i in dataBase)  {


        let descriptionOption = document.createElement('option');
        descriptionOption.textContent=dataBase[i].description;
        descriptionOption.className += 'divider';
        exportList.appendChild(descriptionOption);

        for (let j=0; j<dataBase[i].length; j++)  {
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.subjectType = dataBase[i].property;

                opt.value = dataBase[i].property + j;
                opt.textContent=(dataBase[i][j].name);
                exportList.appendChild(opt);

        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Структуру объекта нельзя изменить? Если "нет", то можно использовать `data-` атрибуты для сохранения типа лица (yl, fl, au) и порядкового номера в объекте. Затем при `onchange` читать атрибуты и по ним получать прямой доступ к объекту.

Comment: @XelaNimed Можно, я пишу с нуля, хотелось бы узнать оптимальный способ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать массив в котором каждый элемент представляет группу значений и имеет дополнительные свойства, например `isDisabled`,  с помощью которых можно реализовать какую-либо безнес-логику:

```js
var store = [{
    displayName: 'Организации',
    items: [{
      name: 'ООО "Рога и копыта"',
      inn: '111111',
      ogrn: '11111111111',
      address: '123456, Тьмутараканск, ул.Пушкина, д.1'
    }, {
      name: 'ООО "АТЕ НАТЕ"',
      isDisabled: true,
      inn: '2222',
      ogrn: '222222222222',
      address: '987654, Гдетогорск, пр.Какойто, д.100'
    }, {
      name: 'ООО "СамОри"',
      inn: '33333',
      ogrn: '3333333333333',
      address: '112233, г.Тамтоярск, пр.Большой, д.99'
    }]
  }, {
    displayName: 'Физ. лица',
    items: [{
      name: 'Петров Петр Петрович',
      address: '445566, г.Глубопопск, пер.Кривой, д.88'
      }, {
      name: 'Сидоров Сидор Сидорович',
      isDisabled: true,
      address: '778899, г.Абэвэйск, ул.Какаято, д.33'
    }]
  }, {
    displayName: 'Арбитражные управляющие',
    items: [{
      name: 'Михайлов Михаил Михайлович',
      inn: '6666666666',
      sro: 'Союз Арбитражных управляющих г.Тутабурга',
      address: 'г.Тутабург, а/я "Михайлов М.М."'
    }]
  }],
  sel = document.querySelector('select'),
  txtArea = document.querySelector('textarea');

// Создаём выпадающий список...
store.forEach(function(grp, grpIdx) {

  let optGrp = document.createElement('optgroup');
      optGrp.label = grp.displayName;
  
  grp.items.forEach(function(opt, itmIdx) {
    
    let option = document.createElement('option');
        option.label = opt.name;
        option.disabled = opt.isDisabled || false;
        option.dataset.grpIdx = grpIdx;
        option.dataset.itmIdx = itmIdx;
    
    optGrp.appendChild(option);
  });

  sel.appendChild(optGrp);
});

sel.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  
  let optIdx = e.target.options.selectedIndex;
  let opt = e.target.options[optIdx];
  let grpIdx = parseInt(opt.dataset.grpIdx);
  let itmIdx = parseInt(opt.dataset.itmIdx);
  let obj = store[grpIdx].items[itmIdx];
  
  for(var key in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
     txtArea.value += key + ' : ' + obj[key] + '\n';
    }
  }
  txtArea.value += '----\n';
     
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected disabled>Выберите значение</option>
</select>
<p>
  <textarea></textarea>
</p>
```

P.S.: старайтесь впредь не использовать реальные данные.

Comment: Элементы "АТЕ НАТЕ" и "Сидоров" не работают.

Comment: @IgorCheglakov см. свойство `isDisabled`.